# Привязка класса css к первой новости в цикле , на движке wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, вёрстка

В цикле указывается класс ко всем новостям, которые будут выводится.
Я взял шаблон, где к первой новости идет класс `post1`:

```
<div id="post-1" class="post1">
```

Нужно, чтобы к последующим новостям выводился класс `post`:

```
<div id="post-2" class="post">
<div id="post-3" class="post">
```

Если задать функцию в *functions.php*:

```
<?php //свой класс у первой записи в цикле start
function wph_first_post_in_query($classes) {
    global $wp_query;
    if (0 == $wp_query->current_post) {
        $classes[] = 'first';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'wph_first_post_in_query');
//свой класс у первой записи в цикле end
?>
```

и вместо `<div class="post" id="post">` задать функцию wp `<div <?php post_class() ?> id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">`, у меня получается задать отдельный стиль для первой новости , но проблема заключается в том, что стиль применяется ко всем новостям полностью , а потом еще к первой отдельно. Мне необходимо, чтобы у первой новости стиль был абсолютно другой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто ввести в цикл вывода постов счётчик, по значению которого определять, какой по счёту пост вы выводите

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) {
    $i = 0;
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $i == 0 ? 'post1' : 'post'; ?>">...</div>
        <?php

        $i++; //не забывайте про инкремент счётчика в каждой итерации
    }
}
```

Обновление для частного случая:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : $i = 0; ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $i == 0 ? 'post1' : 'post'; ?>" id="post"> контент </div>
    <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
    <div class="pagenavi">
        <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } ?>
    </div>
    <?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ , но что то не получается у меня , я немного не пойму как оно работает, я его вставляю в цикл вывода сразу после его открытия ' <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); // если посты есть - запускаем цикл wp ?>'  , после идет ваш код , и после уже идет сама новость '<div class="post" id="post">
     <div class="title">'

Comment: Где-то за пределами цикла определите переменную `$i = 0`. Внутри конструкции `while()` перед самым её концом делайте инкремент `$i++`. Вот этот код `<?php echo $i == 0 ? 'post1' : 'post'; ?>` вставьте в то место, где нужно вывести класс `post1` или `post` в зависимости от условия. Всё, остальной код вывода постов остаётся прежним. Если всё равно не получается, выведите в вопросе весь код для `if (have_posts())`, я помогу с его редактированием

Comment: `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $i++;  ?>
      <div class="<?php echo $i == 0 ? 'post1' : 'post'; ?>" id="post">
                            контент
                 <?php endwhile; ?>
      <div class="pagenavi"><?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } ?></div>
      <?php else : ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php
        $i = 0;
        ?>`

Comment: вот с этим кодом выводятся новости все с классом post , первая новость остается без изменений

Comment: Обновила ответ. Вы перепутали местами присваивание переменной нуля и её инкремент

Comment: я снова запутался ) внутри цикла `while()` я задал инкремент `$i++` e у меня получилось `<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();  $i++;  ?>` после закрытия этого цикла я присвоил переменную нуля `<?php else : ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php
        $i = 0;
        ?>`  и все же не пойму где я перепутал )

Comment: посмотрите мой ответ (http://screencast.com/t/PEjEv63L) выше, в нём ваш цикл со всеми необходимыми правками

Comment: Спасибо огромное)) все получилось )) еще б понять бы как оно так работает )

Comment: Всё очень просто: у вас есть цикл `while()` действия внутри которого повторяются до тех пор, пока не закончатся посты, полученные в запросе. Перед началом этого цикла вы задаёте переменной значение `$i = 0`, а внутри цикла после каждого выполнения набора действий увеличиваете её на единицу `$i++`. То есть при обработке первого поста `$i` будет равна нулю, для второго - единице, для третьего - двум и т. д. Вот эта конструкция `<?php echo $i == 0 ? 'post1' : 'post'; ?>` значит следующее: выведи `post1` если `$i == 0`, иначе выведи `post`.

Comment: Вы кстати, можете выводить разные `id` для своих постов, используя эту же переменную как-то так `id="post-<?php echo $i; ?>"` и получите `post-0`, `post-1`, `post-2` и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное разъяснение) очень помогли )

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать обычный стандартный css псевдо-элемент

```
:first-child
```

или

```
:first-of-type
```

```html
<div id="main" class="posts_list">
    <div id="post-2" class="post"></div>
    <div id="post-2" class="post"></div>
    <div id="post-2" class="post"></div>
   <div id="post-2" class="post"></div>
</div>
```

и в css

```html
.posts_list:first-child{
   some another style
}
```

или

```html
.post:first-of-type{
   some another style
}
```

Comment: Извините , с псевдо-элементами не получается, так как к классу post у меня идет привязка к одним картинкам, а к классу post1 идет привязка к другим картинкам. Получается если задать всем новостям из цикла один и тот же класс, уезжает сам дизайн

Comment: добавтье ещё один класс. 
( в элементы css можно прописывать несколько классов)
    <div class="posts_list">  
        <div class="post post1"> </div>  
        <div class="post post2"> </div>  
   </div>  


при том общие параметры записывайте в класс post
а отличия (к примеру - урл к картинке бекграунда) в post1 post2

Comment: Спасибо ) но проблема и составлялась в том что я не знал как присвоить всем разные классы)) ответом выше мне обьяснили как это сделать )

Comment: Помоги пожалуйста разобраться с comments.php , как и где правильно верстать этот файл , где задать див для начала комментария с ответами и где его конец, у меня выделяются только каждый коммент отдельно , хоть ответ то , хоть и нет .. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496307/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2-comments-php-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wp